# postgresql function - get number of rows affected by update query

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I'm writing one postgresql function that executes some update query. I need to make sure that any rows affected or not and return success/failure message accordingly.

If(rows affected)? then 'update success' else 'update failed'

How to RAISE NOTICE the row count??

```
-- Get count from UPDATE
WITH rows AS (
    UPDATE distributors
    SET dname = 'JKL Widgets'
    WHERE did <= 10
    RETURNING 1
)
SELECT count(*) FROM rows;
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CALL-STACK

Comment: [select number of affected rows to a variable in function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131825/how-to-select-number-of-affected-rows-to-variable-in-function)

Answer (score 4):

[use get diagnostics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS), e.g:

```
t=# create table so17(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so17 values(0);
INSERT 0 1
t=# do $$
declare d int;
begin
update so17 set i = 0 where i=0;
get diagnostics d = row_count;
raise info 'updated: % rows', d;
update so17 set i = 0 where i=1;
get diagnostics d = row_count;
raise info 'updated: % rows', d;
end;
$$;
INFO:  updated: 1 rows
INFO:  updated: 0 rows
DO
```

Comment: I'm executing update query followed by a select query.
Its always returning row count as 1 even update query is failed.

Comment: you should share the code. put get diagnostics STRAIGHT after update, otherwise you get other rows count